# How to match a string wildcard pattern in an excel macro

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a test like

```
LEFT('F13',2)='F1'
```

I want to change it from a left-side match to a test that supports wildcards

```
'F13'='F?3'
```

Excel doesn't support regex except in VBA code but i'd prefer this was done in a macro. I should point out that the actual test isn't a simple string, but cell references (this may be important, I'm not sure):

```
IF(LEFT($DATA.$A$2:$A$1501,LEN($B$3))=$B$3,...
```

The range actually evaluates to a single cell based on where the macro is called from. $B$3 is the pattern input by the user.

Comment: "Excel doesn't support regex except in VBA code but i'd prefer this was done in a macro." I'm confused: macros are written with VBA code. Do you mean to say you'd prefer a pure worksheet function/formula?

Comment: I'm getting mixed up with access I think where 'macros' are distinct from 'VBA functions'. I mean a formula yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=SEARCH("F?3","F13")=1

In your second example, if B3 contains wildcards infused text

=SEARCH(B3,$DATA.$A$2:$A$1501)=1

SEARCH returns the position where it finds the first argument.  The "=1" ensures the string starts with the first argument as opposed to somewhere in the middle.  I'm not sure how your $DATA argument works, so I just copied it verbatim.

Comment: $DATA is a typo due to copying the function from Open Office (which converts formulas to StarBasic). It should say DATA! as it is a worksheet reference.

Comment: This solution fails because search raises a #VALUE error when the string is not found. This breaks the whole formula. Same with FIND. Is there a way to test for #VALUE?

Comment: If you're using 2007, you can use the IFERROR function as an alternative